# Inexplicable TypeError in python that does not contain any of my code in the traceback

Tags: python, flask, typeerror

This bug is driving me nuts. I am trying to create the backend of a website in python using flask. I am getting the following error and traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1577, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 827, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 855, in run_wsgi_app
    app_iter = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Bizarrely, the traceback does not contain any of my files so I can't figure out what's causing it or how to fix it.

Here are the relevant methods that I wrote:

```
@app.route('/notes/<filenum>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view(filenum):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pass
    else:
        if 'username' in session:
            if request.values['fnct'] == "delete":
                asdf = database.delNote(filenum,session['username'])
                return asdf
            return "invalid command"
        else:
            return "not logged in"

def delNote(self, noteid,username):
    try:
        if self.getPost(noteid)[7] == self.usernameToID(username):
            for file in glob.glob('uploads/' + str(noteid)+"-*"):
                os.remove(file)
            self._execute('DELETE FROM Posts where postID=?',(noteid,))
            return 1
        else:
            return -2 #autherror
    except IndexError:
        return -1 #note does not exist
```

When I call delNote(), it works flawlessly without any errors. When I run view(filenum) with the line that calls delNote() commented out, it works flawlessly with no errors. When I call delNote from view, then I get the above error.

It seems that in spite of the error, the function does complete it's intended task. Using print statements, I figured out the entirety of view() runs before the error, but the error is thrown before the `return asdf` line is run. Can someone please explain to me what is going on because I'm resisting the growing temptation of throwing my computer out the window.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, you're returning an integer from your controller and Flask doesn't support that.

Here's the relevant docs:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.make_response

Controllers must return a Response object or a string (or a few other specialized things). You can't return integers, they don't work. That error is because Flask can't figure out what to do with it, so it's assuming it's a callable, and ints are not callables.

The hacktaculuar way of solving your problem is just return str(asdf), but don't do that. It looks like you're trying to show error codes, so you almost certainly want to use the Flask abort() function instead and return the appropriate HTTP status.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your view procedure, I see the following:

```
asdf = database.delNote(filenum,session['username'])
```

There is no return value from the delNote method, so you're assigning `None` to `asdf`.  I'm not familiar with Flask, but it's probably doing something with that value that it ultimately can't handle.  The error you're getting about an `int` not being callable makes sense then, as `None` can be coerced to the integer 0.  There's no need to assign your `delNote` to anything.  Try this and see if it makes a difference:

```
database.delNote(filenum, session['username'])
return "Note deleted."
```

Comment: Whoops, looks like I didn't copy the entire method my accident. I copy and pasted the entire method now

Comment: In that case, it's because your `delNote` method is returning an integer.  You then immediately return that in `view`, which is tripping Flask up as it's expecting a response or string.